# Error with local variable + lambda-function in Java

Tags: java, variables, lambda, syntax-error, local

I got a strange problem about a local variable and a lambdafunction that seems not to be able to deal with it. I keep getting the error-message *"local variable acc defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"*

My code looks like this:

```
Accumulator acc = new Accumulator(0, 0);
stream.reduce(0, (sum, value) -> {
    acc = new Accumulator(sum + value, acc.getB()+1);
    return sum + value;
});
```

So as you can see, I am trying to reduce a stream of integers and keep 2 values instead of just the one from the reducing-process. I am trying to save those values in the little helper class `Accumulator`, which got a `final int a` and a `final int b` to store those. However, it seems like `stream.reduce` can't reach `acc`.

On other parts of my program, including other lambda-functions, similar code-structures work fine (declaring local variables and changing them inside the lambda-function), so I don't know what to do.

Example (the `stream` is initialized of course):

```
ArrayList<StudentRecord> studentList = new ArrayList<StudentRecord>();
stream.forEach(student -> {
    studentList.add(student);
});
```

Help would be appreciated,
Regards

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong: `acc` is not declared `final`. What's the question?

Comment: [Please search before posting](/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+local+variable+defined+in+an+enclosing+scope+must+be+final+or+effectively+final), more on searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: If you post the other code aswell, then we could tell you what the difference is. Otherwise there isn't anything for us to do here.

Comment: The problem is, that I need to re-instantiate `acc` whenever `reduce` calculates the new `sum` which is not possible after declaring it final. As I stated, I managed to get several similar code-structures to work without declaring the variables `final`

Comment: can you not construct the Object in a more simple way

Comment: Don't try to give code in the comments. Please [edit] your question and add all the needed information in it.

Comment: What type of data does your `Stream` contain, and how do you want to reduce it (i.e. what should the output be)?

Comment: @Eran the stream contains `Integers` and should reduce them to their sum. I also need the number of `integers` to be stored, though, and that's why I created the `Accumulator`.

Comment: Maybe the compiler ignores effectively final variables that aren't visible to the outside and not reassigned? Edit the question and I will remove my downvote and upvote instead.

Comment: You're already reducing. Just add `acc` to the accumulator of the reduction.

Comment: I think I have seen this behaviour outlined in another answer to a question that was about lambdas aswell (this question isn't a duplicate though). I can't find it currently though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot assign to a local variable within a lambda expression. However, there are ways to call the `reduce` method that would produce the output you desire.

For example :

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of (1,2,3,4,5);
Accumulator result =
    stream.reduce(new Accumulator(0,0), // initial value
                  (acc, i) -> {acc.a += i;acc.b++; return acc;}, // add current value to
                                                                 // the accumulator
                  (acc1, acc2) -> new Accumulator (acc1.a+acc2.a,acc1.b+acc2.b)); // combine two accumulators
System.out.println ("sum = " + result.a);
System.out.println ("count = " + result.b);
```

This produces just one `Accumulator` instance (unless your `Stream` is parallel). The output `Accumulator` will contain the sum in `acc.a` and the number of elements in `acc.b`.

Output :

```
sum = 15
count = 5
```

I'm assuming this is for educational purposes only. If not, it would make more sense to use `IntStream`'s `summaryStatistics()` which calculates the sum, the number of elements and other properties (min, max and average).

Comment: yes, this is for educational purpose, and we weren't even urged to use a class like Accumulator within the process. I just wanted to implement it ,got stuck and wanted to know why. Thanks for your snippet, it helped me out very much!

Answer (score 1):

The variable must not be declared as final, but it must not be reassigned, so it is effectively final.
In line 3 of your code, you reassign the variable. This is not possible.

If you say, that you have done similar things already with success in other code: I think this is not possible. Probably you Changed the object the variable refers to, but not the variable itself.

Comment: Thank you, that will be it. I wasn't totally sure what "effectively final" means.

Comment: While your answer is probably correct, making this kind of claim without a reference to the java specs or documentation is shunned upon, because you are describing a detail of the spec, which might change in the future. Otherwise please include the current java version you are using where this behaviour is observed by you. Or make sure your claim holds true in different examples first and include them in the answer. I for one know that for the next java version it is/was planned to be changed, so this answer will confuse future visitors.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful Since the question used lamdas we are of course talking about Java 8. In fact, before Java 8, anonymous inner classes could only used variables explicitly declared as final (there was no concept of "effectively final" in Java 7 or prior to Java 7).